# How do I get lazy matching to match correctly?

Tags: regex

Given a string (as seen in the examples below), I would like to extract the following into three groups:

1. **Group 1**: Is the first character a `#` or not
2. **Group 2**: Capture the string between the `#` (if it exists) and the square brackets (if the `[`)
3. **Group 3**: Capture the contents of the square brackets (without the square brackets)

At this stage I have the following regular expression:

```
/^(#)?(.*?)\[?(.*?)\]?$/
```

I am using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ as my testing tool with multiline and global turned on.

#### Example 1:

```
#Sprite[abc]
```

**Expected Result**

1. **Group 1:** #
2. **Group 2:** Sprite
3. **Group 3:** abc

**Actual Result**

1. **Group 1:** #
2. **Group 2:**  // Empty, not NO MATCH
3. **Group 3:** Sprite[abc // No trailing ]

#### Example 2:

```
#Sprite
```

**Expected Result**

1. **Group 1:** #
2. **Group 2:** Sprite
3. **Group 3:** [NO MATCH]

**Actual Result**

1. **Group 1:** #
2. **Group 2:**
3. **Group 3:** Sprite

#### Example 3:

```
Sprite
```

**Expected Result**

1. **Group 1:** [NO MATCH]
2. **Group 2:** Sprite
3. **Group 3:** [NO MATCH]

**Actual Result**

1. **Group 1:** [NO MATCH]
2. **Group 2:** // empty
3. **Group 3:** Sprite

#### Example 4:

```
Sprite[abc]
```

**Expected Result**

1. **Group 1:** [NO MATCH]
2. **Group 2:** Sprite
3. **Group 3:** abc

**Actual Result**

1. **Group 1:** [NO MATCH]
2. **Group 2:** // empty
3. **Group 3:** Sprite[abc

To me it feels like the lazy match in the expression above isn't well being lazy, shouldn't it hit the [ and break out, group, and move on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better be more specific instead of lazy :)

```
(#)?([^\[]*)(?:\[([^\]]*)\])?$
```

works on your examples. Translation:

```
(\#)?       # Match # (optional)
([^\[]*)    # Match any characters except [
(?:         # Try to match...
 \[         #  [, followed by
 ([^\]]*)   #  any characters except ], followed by
 \]         #  ]
)?          # optionally
$           # Match end of string.
```

Comment: Awesome, not only does it work, but the way you have broken down makes sense

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully use the following expression in python:

```
regex = re.compile(r'^(#)?(.*?)(?:\[(.*?)\])?$')
```

The problem was basically the question marks after the brackets (`?` just after `.*?` makes laziness difficult). The question mark now is for the whole expression, that is, `(?:\[(.*?)\])?`.

Note: The `(?:)` is used to avoid capturing the expression (I don't know if that's supported in the tool you're using).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
^(#)?([^\[]*)(?:\[(.*?)\])?$
```